# sqlite error inserting string into db android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to insert the values I get from the `EditText` to the `Mysql` db but I have an error near "," which I hope someone can clarify :

```
final SQLiteDatabase userDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Users",MODE_PRIVATE,null);

    final String fullNameText = fullName.getText().toString();

    final String stateText = state.getText().toString();

    final String zipcodeText = zipcode.getText().toString();

    saveUserInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try
            {

                userDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS allUsers (name VARCHAR, zipcode VARCHAR, state VARCHAR, id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)");

                userDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO allUsers(name, zipcode, state) VALUES ( " + fullNameText + ", " + zipcodeText + ", " + stateText + ")");



                Cursor c = userDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM allUsers", null);

                int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
                int zipcodeIndex = c.getColumnIndex("zipcode");
                int stateIndex = c.getColumnIndex("state");
                int idIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");

                c.moveToFirst();

                while (c != null) {
                    Log.i("Name-", c.getString(nameIndex));
                    Log.i("Zipcode-", c.getString(zipcodeIndex));
                    Log.i("State-", c.getString(stateIndex));

                    Log.i("id", Integer.toString(c.getInt(idIndex)));

                    c.moveToNext();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Error Logs

```
>06-20 17:21:38.498 5433-5433/com.haasith.creation.jantan W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO allUsers(name, zipcode, state) VALUES ( , , )
>06-20 17:21:38.498 5433-5433/com.haasith.creation.jantan W/System.err: #################################################################
>06-20 17:21:38.498 5433-5433/com.haasith.creation.jantan W/System.err: Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
>06-20 17:21:38.498 5433-5433/com.haasith.creation.jantan W/System.err: Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
>06-20 17:21:38.498 5433-5433/com.haasith.creation.jantan W/System.err:     (near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO allUsers(name, zipcode, state) VALUES ( , , ))
>06-20 17:21:38.498 5433-5433/com.haasith.creation.jantan W/System.err: #################################################################
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by:

```
final String fullNameText = fullName.getText().toString();

final String stateText = state.getText().toString();

final String zipcodeText = zipcode.getText().toString();
```

the above code get the **empty string**, for your `OnClickListener` does not get the newest `fullNameText`, `stateText` and `zipcodeText` values.

The correct usage maybe like:

```
saveUserInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        try
        {

         final String fullNameText = fullName.getText().toString();

         final String stateText = state.getText().toString();

         final String zipcodeText = zipcode.getText().toString();

         userDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS allUsers (name VARCHAR, zipcode VARCHAR, state VARCHAR, id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)");

         userDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO allUsers(name, zipcode, state) VALUES ( " + fullNameText + ", " + zipcodeText + ", " + stateText + ")");
```

Comment: String is not a primitive type, it is a reference type. Your answer is correct (he needs to obtain the strings inside the `OnClickListener`), though.

Comment: logcat thinks my final strings are column names >06-21 00:42:46.090 17205-17205/com.haasith.creation.jantan E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: jkjjk
>06-21 00:42:46.090 17205-17205/com.haasith.creation.jantan W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: jkjjk (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO allUsers(name, zipcode, state) VALUES ( jkjjk, 989889, jjknj)  @karakuri

Comment: @chengpohi Either quote the strings, or use parameters.

Comment: @HaasithSanka `userDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO allUsers(name, zipcode, state) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)", new String[]{fullName, zipCode, state});`

Answer (score -1):

Here is your INSERT SQL

```
INSERT INTO allUsers(name, zipcode, state) VALUES ( " + fullNameText + ", " + zipcodeText + ", " + stateText + ")
```

the result string which is

```
INSERT INTO allUsers(name, zipcode, state) VALUES ( Name, ZipCode, StateText)
```

However, you need to quote the string in SQL.

```
INSERT INTO allUsers(name, zipcode, state) VALUES ( 'Name', 'ZipCode', 'StateText')
```

Comment: I want text from edittext to be stored not the string "Name" and etc.

Comment: @HaasithSanka What I mean is the string should be like this `"INSERT INTO allUsers(name, zipcode, state) VALUES ('" + fullNameText + "', '" + zipcodeText + "', '" + stateText + "')"`
You should add `'` to your string.

The string in the answer is the **RESULT STRING** not the statement itself.

Answer (score -1):

`userDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO allUsers(name, zipcode, state) VALUES ( " + fullNameText + ", " + zipcodeText + ", " + stateText + ")");`

The problem is this sql query. It needs from you 3 values, basically name, zipcode and state. Your syntax is wrong in the Values section. It needs to be

`userDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO allUsers(name, zipcode, state) VALUES ( fullNameText, zipcodeText,  stateText)");`

Edit:
And if you want blank space before and.after each value you can write it.like this: " " + fullNameText + " ", etc, etc

Comment: when i tried this i got this error >android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: fullNameText (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO allUsers(name, zipcode, state) VALUES (fullNameText , zipcodeText, stateText) –

Comment: Try this as shown here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-insert-records.htm and add your query as such VALUES("+fullNameText+", etc)

Comment: Check joshua anwer above for strng insertion